# Web page message [object object]

Tags: php, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm using a framework called Ispinia to do a simple system for my Company, and when I try to submit anyting give this error:

[image: screenshot]

Web page message [object object].

I'm using IE11.
Thanks in advance!

CODE: Controller.js

```
function vila_do_conde_ctrl($scope, $http, SweetAlert){   

$scope.dataInicio = new Date();
$scope.dataFim = new Date(); 

$scope.teste = function(){
    alert($scope.myDate);
}

$scope.preencheEmbarques = function(){ 

  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/DIARIODEBORDO/php/preenche_embarques.php?oi="+$scope.oi)
       .then(function (response) {$scope.embarques=response.data.records;$scope.emb = ""; $scope.dataChegada = ""; $scope.dataSaida = ""; $scope.dataDesova = ""; $scope.tipoCarga = ""; if($scope.ctn) $scope.ctn = ""; $scope.fornecedor = ""; $scope.servicoAdd = ""; $scope.qte = ""; $scope.unidade = ""; $scope.dataInicio = ""; $scope.dataFim = ""; $scope.obs = ""; $scope.servicos = ""; }, function (response){alert(response);});


};


$scope.buscaServicos = function(){

 var embarque = encodeURIComponent($scope.emb.trim());

 $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/DIARIODEBORDO/php/preenche_servicos.php?emb="+embarque)
      .then(function (response) {
    $scope.servicos=response.data.records;
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.servicos.length; i++){
        var dataAux = $scope.servicos[i].DataInicio.split("-");
        $scope.servicos[i].DataInicio = dataAux[2]+"/"+dataAux[1]+"/"+dataAux[0];

        dataAux = $scope.servicos[i].DataFim.split("-");
        $scope.servicos[i].DataFim = dataAux[2]+"/"+dataAux[1]+"/"+dataAux[0];
    }

    }, function (response){alert(response);});

};


$scope.preencheDados = function(){ 
    if($scope.emb){

        var embarque = encodeURIComponent($scope.emb.trim());

 $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/DIARIODEBORDO/php/preenche_dados.php?emb="+embarque)
      .then(function (response) {
     $scope.dados=response.data.records[0];

     if($scope.dados.DtChegada){
         $scope.dataAux=$scope.dados.DtChegada.split("-");
         $scope.dataChegada=$scope.dataAux[2]+"/"+$scope.dataAux[1]+"/"+$scope.dataAux[0];
     }

     if($scope.dados.DtSaida){
         $scope.dataAux=$scope.dados.DtSaida.split("-");
         $scope.dataSaida=$scope.dataAux[2]+"/"+$scope.dataAux[1]+"/"+$scope.dataAux[0];  
     }

     if($scope.dados.DtDesova){
         $scope.dataAux=$scope.dados.DtDesova.split("-");
         $scope.dataDesova=$scope.dataAux[2]+"/"+$scope.dataAux[1]+"/"+$scope.dataAux[0]; 
     }


     $scope.tipoCarga=$scope.dados.TipoCarga;
     $scope.ctn=$scope.dados.Container;

     $scope.buscaServicos();

 }, function(response){alert(response);});


}


};

$scope.adicionarServico = function(){

    if($scope.oi && $scope.emb && $scope.fornecedor && $scope.servicoAdd && $scope.qte && $scope.unidade && $scope.dataInicio && $scope.dataFim){
        var embarque = encodeURIComponent($scope.emb.trim());
        var fornecedor = encodeURIComponent($scope.fornecedor.trim());
        var servico = encodeURIComponent($scope.servicoAdd.trim());
        var quantidade = encodeURIComponent($scope.qte);
        var unidade = encodeURIComponent($scope.unidade.trim());

        var data_inicio = encodeURIComponent($scope.dataInicio.getFullYear()+"-"+ ($scope.dataInicio.getMonth() + 1) +"-"+$scope.dataInicio.getDate());

        var data_fim = encodeURIComponent($scope.dataFim.getFullYear()+"-"+ ($scope.dataFim.getMonth() + 1) +"-"+$scope.dataFim.getDate());

        var obs = "";
        if($scope.obs)
            obs = encodeURIComponent($scope.obs);

        var container = ""
        if($scope.tipoCarga){
            if($scope.ctn)
                container = encodeURIComponent($scope.ctn);

            $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/DIARIODEBORDO/php/adicionar_tipo_carga.php?oi="+$scope.oi+"&emb="+embarque+"&ctn="+container)
             .then(function (response) {}, function (response){alert(response);});
        }


        $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/DIARIODEBORDO/php/adicionar_servico.php?oi="+$scope.oi+"&emb="+embarque+"&forn="+fornecedor+"&servico="+servico+"&qte="+quantidade+"&unidade="+unidade+"&dtInicio="+data_inicio+"&dtFim="+data_fim+"&obs="+obs)
             .then(function (response) {
               SweetAlert.swal({
                    title: "Serviço adicionado!",
                    //text: "You clicked the button!",
                    type: "success"
               });
                $scope.buscaServicos();}, function (response){alert(response);});

    }
    else
        alert("Preencha todos os campos!"); 
    };
```

MODEL:

```
<?php

$oi = $_GET['oi'];
$emb = $_GET['emb'];
$fornecedor = $_GET['forn'];
$servico = $_GET['servico'];
$quantidade = $_GET['qte'];
$unidade = $_GET['unidade'];
$data_inicio = $_GET['dtInicio'];
$data_fim = $_GET['dtFim'];
$obs = $_GET['obs'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $base_de_Dados);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($obs != "")

   $sql = "INSERT INTO diario_bordo.servicos (OI, EMBARQUE, FORN_SERVICO, SERVICO, QUANTIDADE, UNIDADE, DATA_INICIO, DATA_FIM, OBSERVACOES) VALUES           ('".$oi."','".$emb."','".$fornecedor."','".$servico."',".$quantidade.",'".$unidade."','".$data_inicio."','".$data_fim."','".$obs."')";

else
   $sql = "INSERT INTO diario_bordo.servicos (OI, EMBARQUE, FORN_SERVICO, SERVICO, QUANTIDADE, UNIDADE, DATA_INICIO, DATA_FIM) VALUES           ('".$oi."','".$emb."','".$fornecedor."','".$servico."',".$quantidade.",'".$unidade."','".$data_inicio."','".$data_fim."')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


  ?>
```

Comment: I guess you'd want to take that up with the framework's support?  We can help with your code, but if something is going wrong inside someone else's black box then we can't really help with that.

Comment: That sounds like a JS issue, not PHP. Not much we can help with though without code.

Comment: Exactly what do you expect us to be able to do? A screen capture of a generic alert() is utterly useless. Without any code, or even a url to look at, there is basically NOTHING we can do.

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is the way JavaScript outputs an object. Not sure what the purpose of your script is, but you can show the sub-object by using `objectname.key`.

e.g. if 'person' is an object containing name and mail address, you can access the sub-objects (probably strings in this example) by calling `person.name` and `person.mailaddress`.

I think you should now go through your code again and have a look at all alert messages.